# I don't understand why the BluetoothDevice is null after bluetooth is disconnected?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-bluetooth

I've just started learning android programming and I'm trying to design it such that when device B(without app) disconnects from device A(with the app), device B can reconnect to device A again. What I've tried is to run startBTConnection after the disconnection is detected, but the BluetoothDevice and socket always becomes null after the disconnect happens.

Connect.java

```
public class Connect extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "Connect";

    public ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> myBTDevicesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> myBTPairedDevicesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public DeviceListAdapter myDeviceListAdapter;
    public DeviceListAdapter myPairedDeviceListAdapter;

    BluetoothConnectionService myBluetoothConnection;

    //Bounded Device
    static BluetoothDevice myBTDevice;
    BluetoothDevice myBTConnectionDevice;

    BluetoothAdapter myBluetoothAdapter;

    ListView lvNewDevices;
    static ListView lvPairedDevices;
    ImageButton btnSend;
    EditText sendMessage;
    Button btnSearch;
    StringBuilder incomingMsg;
    TextView incomingMsgTextView;
    Button bluetoothConnect;
    TextView deviceSearchStatus;
    ProgressDialog myProgressDialog, connectionDialog;
    TextView pairedDeviceText;
    Intent connectIntent;

    //UUID
    public static final UUID myUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    public static BluetoothDevice getBluetoothDevice() {
        return myBTDevice;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_connect);


        bluetoothConnect = findViewById(R.id.connectBtn);
        btnSearch = findViewById(R.id.searchBtn);
        lvNewDevices = findViewById(R.id.listNewDevice);
        lvPairedDevices = findViewById(R.id.pairedDeviceList);
        btnSend = findViewById(R.id.btSend);
        sendMessage = findViewById(R.id.messageText);
        incomingMsgTextView = findViewById(R.id.incomingText);
        deviceSearchStatus = findViewById(R.id.deviceSearchStatus);
        pairedDeviceText = findViewById(R.id.pairedDeviceText);
        incomingMsg = new StringBuilder();
        myBTDevice = null;


        //REGISTER BROADCAST RECEIVER FOR IMCOMING MSG
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(btConnectionReceiver, new IntentFilter("btConnectionStatus"));

        //REGISTER BROADCAST RECEIVER FOR IMCOMING MSG
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter("IncomingMsg"));

        //REGISTER BROADCAST WHEN BOND STATE CHANGES (E.G PAIRING)
        IntentFilter bondFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(bondingBroadcastReceiver, bondFilter);

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(myBluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(discoverabilityBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);

        IntentFilter BTIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(enableBTBroadcastReceiver, BTIntent);

        IntentFilter discoverDevicesIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(discoveryBroadcastReceiver, discoverDevicesIntent);

        IntentFilter discoverStartedIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
        registerReceiver(discoveryStartedBroadcastReceiver, discoverStartedIntent);

        IntentFilter discoverEndedIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        registerReceiver(discoveryEndedBroadcastReceiver, discoverEndedIntent);

        myBTDevicesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        myBTPairedDevicesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        myBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


        //ONCLICKLISTENER FOR SEARCH BUTTON
        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: search button");
                enableBT();
                myBTDevicesArrayList.clear();
            }
        });

        //ONCLICKLISTENER FOR CONNECT BUTTON
        bluetoothConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (myBTDevice == null) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Connect.this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(Connect.this, "No Paired Device! Please Search/Select a Device.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (myBluetoothAdapter.getProfileConnectionState(BluetoothHeadset.HEADSET) == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(Connect.this, "Bluetooth Already Connected",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onClick: connect button");

                    //START CONNECTION WITH THE BOUNDED DEVICE
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent();
                    intent1.setAction("com.example.mdpandroidcontroller.btConnectionStatus");
                    intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
                    sendBroadcast(intent1);

                    startBTConnection(myBTDevice, myUUID);
                }
                lvPairedDevices.setAdapter(myPairedDeviceListAdapter);
            }
        });

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "ConnectActivity: onDestroyed: destroyed");
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(discoverabilityBroadcastReceiver);
        unregisterReceiver(discoveryBroadcastReceiver);
        unregisterReceiver(bondingBroadcastReceiver);
        unregisterReceiver(discoveryStartedBroadcastReceiver);
        unregisterReceiver(discoveryEndedBroadcastReceiver);
        unregisterReceiver(enableBTBroadcastReceiver);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(btConnectionReceiver);


    }

    //BROADCAST RECEIVER FOR BLUETOOTH CONNECTION STATUS
    BroadcastReceiver btConnectionReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Receiving btConnectionStatus Msg!!!");

            String connectionStatus = intent.getStringExtra("ConnectionStatus");
            myBTConnectionDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra("Device");

            //DISCONNECTED FROM BLUETOOTH CHAT
            if (connectionStatus.equals("disconnect")) {

                Log.d("ConnectAcitvity:", "Device Disconnected");

                //CHECK FOR NOT NULL
                if (connectIntent != null) {

                    stopService(connectIntent);
                }

                //RECONNECT DIALOG MSG
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Connect.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("BLUETOOTH DISCONNECTED");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Connection with device has ended. Do you want to reconnect?");
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                startBTConnection(myBTConnectionDevice, myUUID);

                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.show();
            }

            //SUCCESSFULLY CONNECTED TO BLUETOOTH DEVICE
            else if (connectionStatus.equals("connect")) {


                Log.d("ConnectAcitvity:", "Device Connected");
                if(myBTConnectionDevice != null){
                    Toast.makeText(Connect.this, "Connection Established: " + myBTConnectionDevice.getName(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            //BLUETOOTH CONNECTION FAILED
            else if (connectionStatus.equals("connectionFail")) {
                Toast.makeText(Connect.this, "Connection Failed: " + myBTConnectionDevice.getName(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    };


    /*
        Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND (Enable Discoverability).
    */
    private final BroadcastReceiver discoverabilityBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED)) {
                int mode = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_SCAN_MODE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

                switch (mode) {
                    case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE:
                        Log.d(TAG, "OnReceiver: DISCOVERABILITY ENABLED");

                        startSearch();

                        //START BLUETOOTH CONNECTION SERVICE WHICH WILL START THE ACCEPTTHREAD TO LISTEN FOR CONNECTION
                        connectIntent = new Intent(Connect.this, BluetoothConnectionService.class);
                        connectIntent.putExtra("serviceType", "listen");
                        startService(connectIntent);
                        Constants.setConnected(true);

                        checkPairedDevice();


                        myBluetoothConnection = new BluetoothConnectionService();


                        break;
                    //DEVICE IS NOT IN DISCOVERABLE MODE
                    case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE:
                        Log.d(TAG, "OnReceiver: DISCOVERABILITY DISABLED, ABLE TO RECEIVE CONNECTION");
                        break;
                    //BLUETOOTH TURNING ON STATE
                    case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_NONE:
                        Log.d(TAG, "OnReceiver: DISCOVERABILITY DISABLED, NOT ABLE TO RECEIVE CONNECTION");
                        break;
                    //BLUETOOTH TURNED ON STATE
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTING:
                        Log.d(TAG, "OnReceiver: CONNECTING");
                        break;
                    //BLUETOOTH TURNED ON STATE
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTED:
                        Log.d(TAG, "OnReceiver: CONNECTED");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    };


    /*
      Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND (Get Discovered Devices Info).
  */
    private final BroadcastReceiver discoveryBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.d(TAG, "SEARCH ME!");

            if (action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)) {

                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                myBTDevicesArrayList.add(device);
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Connect.this, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "OnReceive: " + device.getName() + ": " + device.getAddress());
                myDeviceListAdapter = new DeviceListAdapter(context, R.layout.device_adapter_view, myBTDevicesArrayList);
                lvNewDevices.setAdapter(myDeviceListAdapter);

            }
        }
    };


    /*
      Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED  (Start Discovering Devices).
  */
    private final BroadcastReceiver discoveryStartedBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();

            if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED)) {

                Log.d(TAG, "STARTED DISCOVERY!!!");
            }
        }
    };


    /*
      Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED  (End Discovering Devices).
  */
    private final BroadcastReceiver discoveryEndedBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();

            if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED)) {

                Log.d(TAG, "ENDED DISCOVERY!!!");
            }
        }
    };


    /*
        Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND (Pairing Devices).
    */
    private final BroadcastReceiver bondingBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();

            if (action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED)) {

                //BONDING DEVICE
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                //BluetoothConnectionService.setMyDevice(device);

                //BOUNDED ALREADY
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Connect.this, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                }
                if (device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "BoundReceiver: Bond Bonded with: " + device.getName());
                    //BluetoothConnectionService.setMyDevice(device);

                    myProgressDialog.dismiss();

                    Toast.makeText(Connect.this, "Bound Successfully With: " + device.getName(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    myBTDevice = device;
                    checkPairedDevice();
                    lvNewDevices.setAdapter(myDeviceListAdapter);

                    Constants.setConnected(true);
                }
                //BONDING WITH ANOTHER DEVICES
                if (device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "BoundReceiver: Bonding With Another Device");

                    myProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Connect.this, "Bonding With Device", "Please Wait...", true);

                    Constants.setConnected(true);

                }
                //BREAKING A BOND
                if (device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "BoundReceiver: Breaking Bond");

                    if (myProgressDialog != null && myProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        myProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                    //DIALOG MSG POPUP
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Connect.this).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Bonding Status");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Bond Disconnected!");
                    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    alertDialog.show();

                    Constants.setConnected(false);

                    myBTDevice = null;
                }

            }
        }
    };

    /*
        TURN DISCOVERABILITY ON
    */
    private void discoverabilityON() {
        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 900);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        }
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);
    }


    /* START DISCOVERING OTHER DEVICES */
    private void startSearch() {
        Log.d(TAG, "btnDiscover: Looking for unpaired devices.");

        //DISCOVER OTHER DEVICES
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        }
        if (myBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            myBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            Log.d(TAG, "BTDiscovery: canceling discovery");

            //check BT permission in manifest
            //checkBTPermission();
            myBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            Log.d(TAG, "BTDiscovery: enable discovery");
        }
        if (!myBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            //check BT permission in manifest
            //checkBTPermission();
            myBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            Log.d(TAG, "BTDiscovery: enable discovery");
        }
    }


    /*
        START BLUETOOTH CHAT SERVICE METHOD
    */
    public void startBTConnection(BluetoothDevice device, UUID uuid) {

        Log.d(TAG, "StartBTConnection: Initializing RFCOM Bluetooth Connection");

        //myBluetoothConnection.startClient(device, uuid);

        connectIntent = new Intent(Connect.this, BluetoothConnectionService.class);
        connectIntent.putExtra("serviceType", "connect");
        connectIntent.putExtra("device", device);
        connectIntent.putExtra("id", uuid);

        Log.d(TAG, "StartBTConnection: Starting Bluetooth Connection Service!");

        startService(connectIntent);
        Constants.setConnected(true);
    }


    public void checkPairedDevice() {
        //CHECK IF THERE IS PAIRED DEVICES
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        }
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = myBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        myBTPairedDevicesArrayList.clear();

        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {

            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                Log.d(TAG, "PAIRED DEVICES: " + device.getName() + "," + device.getAddress());
                myBTPairedDevicesArrayList.add(device);
            }
            pairedDeviceText.setText("Paired Devices: ");
            myPairedDeviceListAdapter = new DeviceListAdapter(this, R.layout.device_adapter_view, myBTPairedDevicesArrayList);
            lvPairedDevices.setAdapter(myPairedDeviceListAdapter);
        } else {
            /*String[] noDevice = {"No Device"};
            ListAdapter emptyListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.device_adapter_view,R.id.deviceName, noDevice);
            lvPairedDevices.setAdapter(emptyListAdapter);*/
            pairedDeviceText.setText("No Paired Devices: ");

            Log.d(TAG, "NO PAIRED DEVICE!!");
        }
    }
}
```

BluetoothConnectionService.java

```
public class BluetoothConnectionService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "BTConnectionAService";
    private static final String appName = "App";

    //UUID
    private static final UUID myUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    private BluetoothAdapter myBluetoothAdapter;

    private AcceptThread myAcceptThread;
    private ConnectThread myConnectThread;
    public BluetoothDevice myDevice;
    private UUID deviceUUID;
    private Handler mHandler;

    Context myContext;
    ProgressDialog myProgressDialog;

    private static String BLUETOOTH_CONNECTION_TAG = "Bluetooth (Connection)";
    private int mState;

    public interface ConnectionConstants {
        // Constants that indicate the current connection state
        int STATE_DISCONNECTED = 0;       
        int STATE_CONNECTING = 1; 
        int STATE_CONNECTED = 2; 
    }

    public BluetoothConnectionService() {

        super("BluetoothConnectionService");
        // mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    }


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {

        myContext = getApplicationContext();
        myBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if (intent.getStringExtra("serviceType").equals("listen")) {

            myDevice = (BluetoothDevice) intent.getExtras().getParcelable("device");

            Log.d(TAG, "Service Handle: startAcceptThread");

            startAcceptThread();
        } else {
            myDevice = (BluetoothDevice) intent.getExtras().getParcelable("device");
            deviceUUID = (UUID) intent.getSerializableExtra("id");

            Log.d(TAG, "Service Handle: startClientThread");

            startClientThread(myDevice, deviceUUID);
        }

    }


    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {

        private BluetoothSocket mySocket;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, UUID uuid) {

            Log.d(TAG, "ConnectThread: started");
            myDevice = device;
            deviceUUID = uuid;
        }

        public void run() {
            BluetoothSocket temp = null;
            Intent connectionStatusIntent;

            Log.d(TAG, "Run: myConnectThread");

            /* Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with given BluetoothDevice */
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "ConnectThread: Trying to create InsecureRFcommSocket using UUID: " + myUUID);
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(BluetoothConnectionService.this, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                }
                temp = myDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(deviceUUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "ConnectThread: Could not create InsecureRFcommSocket " + e.getMessage());
            }

            mySocket = temp;

            //Cancel discovery to prevent slow connection
            myBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "Connecting to Device: " + myDevice);
                //Blocking call and will only return on a successful connection / exception
                mySocket.connect();

                //BROADCAST CONNECTION MSG
                connectionStatusIntent = new Intent("btConnectionStatus");
                connectionStatusIntent.putExtra("ConnectionStatus", "connect");
                connectionStatusIntent.putExtra("Device", myDevice);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(myContext).sendBroadcast(connectionStatusIntent);

                Log.d(TAG, "run: ConnectThread connected");

                //START BLUETOOTH CHAT
                BluetoothChat.connected(mySocket, myDevice, myContext);

                //CANCEL ACCEPT THREAD FOR LISTENING
                if (myAcceptThread != null) {
                    myAcceptThread.cancel();
                    myAcceptThread = null;
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                //Close socket on error
                try {
                    mySocket.close();

                    connectionStatusIntent = new Intent("btConnectionStatus");
                    connectionStatusIntent.putExtra("ConnectionStatus", "connectionFail");
                    connectionStatusIntent.putExtra("Device", myDevice);

                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(myContext).sendBroadcast(connectionStatusIntent);
                    Log.d(TAG, "run: Socket Closed: Connection Failed!! " + e.getMessage());

                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "myConnectThread, run: Unable to close socket connection: " + e1.getMessage());
                }

            }

            try {
                //Dismiss Progress Dialog when connection established
                //myProgressDialog.dismiss();
                //mHandler.post(new DisplayToast(getApplicationContext(),"Connection Established With: "+myDevice.getName()));
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "Cancel: Closing Client Socket");
                mySocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Cancel: Closing mySocket in ConnectThread Failed " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void startAcceptThread() {

        Log.d(TAG, "start");

        //Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (myConnectThread != null) {
            myConnectThread.cancel();
            myConnectThread = null;
        }
        if (myAcceptThread == null) {
            myAcceptThread = new AcceptThread();
            myAcceptThread.start();
        }
    }

    public void startClientThread(BluetoothDevice device, UUID uuid) {

        Log.d(TAG, "startClient: Started");

        myConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device, uuid);
        myConnectThread.start();
    }
}
```

error code

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.getName()' on a null object reference
                                                                                                        at com.example.mdpandroidcontroller.Connect$6.onReceive(Connect.java:347)
                                                                                                        at androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:313)
                                                                                                        at androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:121)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7918)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```